# Plotlyjs update toimage on user click

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

This is my code below, I want to keep the image in Plotly.toImage but only change the layout coordinates( it will have a white square in the middle that changes based on the eventdata   or in other words "

```
      layout.shapes[0].x0=eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"];"
```

) This doesn't seem to work any help?

```
   var img_jpg= d3.select('#jpg-export');

 var img_png= d3.select('#png-export');
 var svg = d3.select('#svg-export');
 var redi= Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
redi.then(
function(gd)
 {
  Plotly.toImage(gd,{height:700,width:700})
     .then(
        function(url)
     {
         img_jpg.attr("src", url);
         Plotly.toImage(gd,{format:'jpeg',height:700,width:700});

     }

     )
});

myDiv.on('plotly_relayout',
function(eventdata){  
    console.log( eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"]);
    console.log(layout.shapes[0]);
   // layout.shapes[0].x0=eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"];
   // layout.shapes[0].x1=eventdata["xaxis.range[1]"];

  Plotly.toImage(redi,{height:700,width:700})
     .then(
        function(url)
     {
         img_jpg.attr("src", url);
         Plotly.toImage(redi,{format:'jpeg',height:700 ,width:700});

     }

     );
    console.log("changes!");
    console.log( eventdata["xaxis.range[0]"]);
    console.log(layout.shapes[0].x0);
    localStorage.setItem("slimshady", JSON.stringify(eventdata));


});
```